# Setting cookies using a servlet called from a java client

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, localhost

My objective is to set a cookie from within a servlet called from a java client, and get the cookie when a different servlet is called from the browser.
The java client has an authenticated session with the server.
The server runs locally.
I tried suggestions from a different question and rename put an alias domain name in my hosts file.
I manually set the domain of the cookie to the alias domain, but it still won't return on the server.
request.getRemoteHost() returns 127.0.0.1 in both servlets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cookie is held in memory (or on disk, but at a specific place) by each client. A Java client and a browser don't share cookies. Two different browsers (IE and Firefox, for example) don't share cookies either. There is no way to do what you want.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I suspected this may be the case.